Create multiple programs inside the same anchor init directory
Is there a way, that I can configure multiple programs in the Anchor.toml file ? I generated a new for my second program using this command:
solana-keygen new --outfile ./target/deploy/<program-name>-keypair.json

This genarated a new keypair.json file. I put it in the Anchor.toml file like this:
[toolchain]

[features]
resolution = true
skip-lint = false

[programs.localnet]
counter = "8n8Dudd3hQzax83hDUqrcMLYRbMjs2M5RTqaKqWLJ42f"
expense-tracker = "EQy5Heu8XD8woQyuhbJV2rp9ikE7etATnTKtwhPLxwN"

[registry]
url = "https://api.apr.dev"

[provider]
cluster = "Localnet"
wallet = "~/.config/solana/id.json"

[scripts]
test = "yarn run ts-mocha -p ./tsconfig.json -t 1000000 tests/**/*.ts"

Now I should be able to write the expense-tracker contract inside the programs directory, but its giving me unresolved imports all over.
My question is how can I write multiple contracts in the same anchor template, like we can do in hardhat. I don't want to create the whole anchor init <program-name> thing, whenever I want to write a contract.
Is it possible ?

anchor init is for generating the anchor project.
anchor init PROJECT_NAME

To generate a new program inside you project, you'll need to use anchor new inside your project
anchor new PROGRAM_NAME

you can check out the soundwork programs which contain multiple programs -> https://github.com/SoundWorkLabs/marketplace-contracts

Thanks, that's what I was asking about !! I will surely check it out :)
